# How do I sort a NSMutableArray by NSString length?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, ios, sorting

I have a NSMutableArray containing NSStrings of various lengths. How would I go about sorting the array by the string length?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

See my answer to [sorting arrays with custom objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc= [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"length" ascending:YES];

[myArray sortUsingDescriptors:@[sortDesc]];
```

Answer (score 5):

This is how I did it (love me some blocks!)

```
_objects = [matchingWords sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
        NSNumber *alength = [NSNumber numberWithInt:((NSString*)a).length];
        NSNumber *blength = [NSNumber numberWithInt:((NSString*)b).length];
        return [alength compare:blength];
    }];
```